# Change the public folder of Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I was looking for a way to change the public's folder name in laravel 5.1, since my host only allows me to use a htdocs folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed these steps, mentioned here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5 :

1. in `bootstrap/app.php`, add

   ```
   $app->bind('path.public', function() {
         return base_path('htdocs');
   });
   ```
2. Then, in `/server.php`, change the two occurences of `public`to `htdocs` (Or whatever you wan to use).

I sincerely hope that'll work in every situation.

### Edit 2016-10-18 :

I recently had to do the same, but this time my host allowed me to delete the "htdocs" folder (And I had a ssh access) :

- I installed Laravel in the root folder, below the "htdocs" folder
- I deleted the "htdocs" folder
- I created a symbolic link to map "htdocs" to "public" : `ln -s public htdocs`

Comment: @michael, where should I put it ?

Comment: Hum ... I'm noticing my files stored on htdocs/something are not available anymore ... Looking through it, I'll post an update as soon as I've covered that.

Comment: Ok, the php artisan serve command calls vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php::publicPath(), where the 'public' string is hardcoded. I updated it, but this is not very futureproof, unless it is only called by artisan serve.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it.. updates and other things work perfectly till now..

make a new folder on root.. and move all folders inside it(ill call it "myfolder" for example).. then move files inside public folder to root.. so it should look like..

```
/myfolder/
/index.php
/server.php
/.htaccess
/favicon
```

so open server.php with text editor and replace with this code..

> ```
> <?php
>
> /**
>  * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
>  *
>  * @package  Laravel
>  * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
>  */
>
> $uri = urldecode(
>     parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
> );
>
> // This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
> // built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
> // application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
> if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$uri)) {
>     return false;
> }
>
> require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
> ```

then on index.php

> ```
> <?php
>
> /**
>  * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
>  *
>  * @package  Laravel
>  * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
>  */
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Register The Auto Loader
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
> | our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
> | into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
> | loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
> |
> */
>
> require __DIR__.'/myfolder/bootstrap/autoload.php';
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Turn On The Lights
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
> | This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
> | will load up this application so that we can run it and send
> | the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
> |
> */
>
> $app = require_once __DIR__.'/myfolder/bootstrap/app.php';
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Run The Application
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
> | through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
> | the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
> | and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
> |
> */
>
> $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
>
> $response = $kernel->handle(
>     $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
> );
>
> $response->send();
>
> $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
> ```

then go to "/myfolder/bootstrap/autoload.php"..

> ```
> <?php
>
> define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Register The Composer Auto Loader
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
> | for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
> | into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
> | loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
> |
> */
>
> require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Include The Compiled Class File
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | To dramatically increase your application's performance, you may use a
> | compiled class file which contains all of the classes commonly used
> | by a request. The Artisan "optimize" is used to create this file.
> |
> */
>
> $compiledPath = __DIR__.'/cache/compiled.php';
>
> if (file_exists($compiledPath)) {
>     require $compiledPath;
> }
> ```

and app.php inside same folder

> ```
> <?php
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Create The Application
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
> | which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
> | the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
> |
> */
>
> $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
>     realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
> );
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Bind Important Interfaces
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
> | we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
> | incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
> |
> */
>
> $app->singleton(
>     Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
>     App\Http\Kernel::class
> );
>
> $app->singleton(
>     Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
>     App\Console\Kernel::class
> );
>
> $app->singleton(
>     Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
>     App\Exceptions\Handler::class
> );
>
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Return The Application
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
> | the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
> | from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
> |
> */
>
> return $app;
> ```

Works well for me on development and production environment..

Comment: Yeah, that seems a good alternative when you can't have anything below the public folder. Thanks for the method.

Comment: you can change paths on these files to suit your need :)