# Remove public from URL Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and would remove public from my URL. Any ideas how this is done without renaming files?

Comment: where you want to remove it? on your local machine or any live server ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806542/change-the-public-folder-of-laravel-5-1

Comment: @Steve, if my answer was helpful, please choose my answer as best answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should point your web server (Nginx, Apache, etc) to the `public` folder, not to the `root` folder (where `app`, `config`, `public`, etc live).

Answer (score 1):

Change your webserver's root directory to the public folder.

For example, an NGINX configuration is below:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           local.dev;
  client_max_body_size 1m;

  root /var/www/html/PROJECT/public;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/nxv_vfoa8j7qzdhl.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/nxv_vfoa8j7qzdhl.error.log;

  location / {

    root  /var/www/html/PROJECT/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     autoindex on;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;


  }
  location ~ \.php$ {

    root  /var/www/html/PROJECT/public;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;

  }
  sendfile off;
}
```